# Randomize uppercasing / lowercasing on all string characters

Tags: javascript, random, dom-manipulation, css

Kind of an odd request, I know. But I've been looking for a solution to this for quite a while now. This is the effect I'm looking for:

```
var myString = "Hello I am randomly capitalized"
```

Desired function result:

```
hElLO i aM rAnDOmlY caPiTAlizED
```

I imagine this is best done with javascript arrays in one way or another. Just looking for some creative ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way

```
myString.split('').map(function(c){
    return c[Math.round(Math.random())?'toUpperCase':'toLowerCase']();
}).join('');
```

You could add this as a prototype method on the string object for easy access if desired:

```
String.prototype.toRandomCase = function() {
    return this.split('').map(function(c){
        return c[Math.round(Math.random())?'toUpperCase':'toLowerCase']();
    }).join('');
}
```

Then access by

```
console.log(myString.toRandomCase());
```

---

## A bit of an explanation of how this works:

1. `String.split` method is used to split the string into an array of individual characters.
2. `Array.map` function is used. This takes a callback function that is applied to each item in an array, and returns a new resulting array with each value returned by the map function.
3. Inside the map function

   1. `Math.round(Math.random())` is used for randomness
   2. The result of that is used with a ternary operator to get `toLowerCase` or `toUpperCase`
      `Math.Round(Math.random())?'toLowerCase':'toUpperCase'`
   3. The result of the ternary operator is used to access the relevant function property by array deferencing of the character, then called. `c[<ternary here>]()`
4. Finally it uses `Array.join` method on the result of the `map` function call to join the resulting array back into a string.

## Code golf (efficiency)

RobG's answer has a more efficient approach than mine (please upvote his answer)

```
String.prototype.toRandomCase = function() {
    return this.toLowerCase().split('').map(function(c){
        return Math.random() < .5? c : c.toUpperCase();
    }).join('');
}
```

If anyone has suggestions for improving this further - please comment or edit this part of the answer

Comment: Great. Let me give this a whirl. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm - this would be an interesting thing for code golfing!

Comment: Rather than `Math.round` you can use `.5>`, which is less to type and one less function call.

Comment: Works wonderfully man. Thank you very much. There's a ton to learn within that function.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll edit and add a breakdown of how it works for you :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, based on Joel's answer…

```
myString.toLowerCase().split('').map(function(c){
    return Math.random() < .5? c : c.toUpperCase();
}).join('');
```